# Ruby on Rails - self made Scaffold doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, blogs

I'm new in Ruby on Rails and I'm creating my own Ruby on Rails - Blog... For my tweets I'm creating a selfmade Scaffold...

Even i press the submit button.. for my new post.. i will get this error msg:

```
uninitialized constant PostsController
```

Here are my files:

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a new Tweet</h1>
 <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :title %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :content %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

blog_controller.rb

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
def new
    @post = Post.new
end
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    redirect_to @post
 end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Me::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :posts
 resources :post
 match '/' => 'blog#home'
 match '/archiv' => 'blog#archiv'
 match '/tweets' => 'blog#new'

 root :to => 'blog#home'
end
```

I made a model with these syntax:

```
rails g model post title:string content:text
```

And at least `rake db:migrate`

Comment: solved by mayself:
created a new controller and made there my blog-formular.. it works now

Comment: i can't :D.. i'm new here

Comment: You can answer your own question. Look at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by myself: made a new controller